# Posting to Microsoft Cognitive Face API using Ionic - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

Currently I am using Ionic to develop a **Facial Recognition** app. 
I am using Microsoft's [Face API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api/documentation/overview) for the same.

My problem is I keep getting `Error 400: Decoding error, image format unsupported.`

After doing some research, I ran into this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6ecc1daf-6fe5-46d4-94b0-101043c9ed28/decoding-error-image-format-unsupported-in-face-api-when-using-binary-data?forum=mlapi)

Quoting START,

> When you're submitting a binary payload, you should **not** base64 encode it.  Here's what you might do instead..

```
URI uri = builder.build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "...");

File file = new File("..."); 
FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
request.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

Quoting END

With Ionic/AngularJS, the captured image using Device Camera or selected from Image Gallery is returned in the form of base64 string. So I looked for ways to decode the data into Binary using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746) but still failed.

Here's my controller code where I make the API call.

```
$scope.postToAPI = function () {
             // make http call to MS cognitive API
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', $scope.picture);
                $http.post($scope.cognitiveServices.endpoint, formData, {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':$scope.cognitiveServices.apiKey }
                }).success(function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    alert("Awesome");
                }).error(function (err) {
                    alert("Fail ->" + err.code + " " + err.message);
                    console.log("Some error occured");
                });
            }
```

I have

- tried setting transform:angular.identity and Content-Type: undefined
- tried sending image without Form Data (just a random trial)
- tried converting base64 string to Uint8 Array (by following the solution to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript))

All my attempts so far have failed. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

*P.S*: This is my first time with Ionic framework.

Comment: Maybe have a try on transform:angular.identity with Content-Type: application/octet-stream?

Comment: How about you use a 3rd party provider to store the image from the camera and then use that URL to upload it to the Face Recognition API?